# помогите как передать List через bundle сейчас передаются данные и принимаются но только данные одной страны даже если нажал на другую страну

Tags: android

```
private fun onClick(model: CountryModel) {
        val fragment = InfoFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putStringArrayList("country", ArrayList(model.country))
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fr_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
}    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        binding.rv.adapter = adapter
        val selectedCountries = arguments?.getStringArrayList("country")
        selectedCountries?.let { countries ->
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                for (selectedCountry in countries) {
                    Log.d("InfoFragment", "Calling loadPlayer for country: $selectedCountry")
                    viewModel.loadPlayer(selectedCountry)
                }
                viewModel.football.collect { state ->
                    Log.d("InfoFragment", "Received football state: $state")
                    adapter.submitList(state.player)
                }
```

"Germany" -> listOf(
PlayerModel(1, "Player1_Germany", 25, R.drawable.qatar, R.drawable.qatar, "Germany"),

```
    )
    "England" -> listOf(
        PlayerModel(1, "Player1_England", 24, R.drawable.qatar, R.drawable.qatar, "England"),
```

Comment: Что есть `model.country` у вас?

Comment: val country:List<String>, лист со странами 4 страны в репозитории мок,,,  нажатие есть данные передаются но только передаются данные только одной страны даже если нажал на другие

Comment: Смотрите код, где заполняете `model.country`.

Comment: в адаптере ? или fun bind(model: CountryModel) {
            binding.tvGroupA.text = model.group[0]
            Glide.with(binding.root).load(model.img[0]).into(binding.imgCountry)
            Glide.with(binding.root).load(model.img[1]).into(binding.imgCountry2)
            Glide.with(binding.root).load(model.img[2]).into(binding.imgCountry3)
            binding.tvCountryName.text = model.country[0]
            binding.tvCountryName2.text = model.country[1]
            binding.tvCountryName3.text = model.country[2] itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onClick(model)

Comment: Там где "нажал на другие" и они записались для передачи в фрагмент.